# How to send auth tokens from the client with Falcor

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

Now I have following code on the client:

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
    source: new falcor.HttpDataSource('/model.json')
});
```

I completely understand how to handle tokens on the server side using falcor-router class. My question is *how to send tokens* with each request from the browser (how to change code above)? I just couldn't find any information. As soon as falcor hides network from developer I expect it to have some options for HTTP requests.

I would really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [gdi2290](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/550)

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
    source: new falcor.HttpDataSource( '/model.json', {
        // Options here
        headers: {
            // Any headers here
            'Authorization': `bearer ' + token` // JWT
        },
        withCredentials: true, // Cookies
        crossDomain: true // CORS
    })
});
```